Supercollider: why assigning SinOsc to a variable x won't allow to plot the variable
I'm new to Supercollider, couldn't find a lot of resources to learn from, so I'm proceeding by attempts and intuitions to some extent.
I can get a wonderful sine wave with this line of code
{SinOsc.ar(freq: 440.0  , phase: 0.0, mul: 0.7  , add: 0.0)}.plot;


But i'm only gettig a flat line with this one
(
x=SinOsc.ar(freq: 440.0  , phase: 0.0, mul: 0.7  , add: 0.0);
{x}.plot;
)


To me those two statements seem equivalent, but I'm obviously missing something crucial.
What is happening behing the scenes?
Why/how are they actually different?

I think you want x={SinOsc.ar(...)}; followed by x.plot - note that the curly braces are in a different place.  You are evaluating SinOsc at a single point, rather than defining a function, and then plotting a function that returns that single point value.

@jasonharper I can see your variation working fine... but I still can't understand why mine doesn't. In my example x.class still results in BinaryOpUGen, why does it make such a difference creating a function earlier (in your example) or later (in mine)?
